# How do you include complete url in twitter?

Tags: twitter, href

I am using the underbelow link reference to publish share the link and title on twitter but when I am clicking on the link only

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=test+http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/show_post.pl?view_mode=single&post_id=134
```

but the tweet being generated, by the above link have url till

```
http://www.test.com/cgi-bin/show_post.pl?view_mode=single
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=test+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Fcgi-bin%2Fabc.pl%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2
```

All the special character in the shared link, need to be converted into hexa character